# How to debug headers sent errors in Node.js

Tags: node.js, header

I'm getting a lot of `Can't set headers after they are sent` errors, and they never seem to give me line numbers in my `app.js`, is this normal? How do people debug these errors?

My code that is throwing the headers error looks like this, is it doing something weird to hide the line numbers?

```
app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.param('q')) {
        searchProvider.search(
            req.param('q'),
            function( error, results) {
                res.render('search', {
                    locals: {
                        results: results,
                        q: req.param('q')
                    },
                });
            }
        );
    } else {
        res.render('index');
    }
});
```

Comment: You are probably calling res.send after writing headers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Can't set headers after they are sent`

Is a common error which means your basically calling `res.render`, `res.end` or `res.send` multiple times. This means your trying to write multiple HTTP responses to one HTTP request (this is invalid).

A common cause of this bug is calling `next` twice in a piece of middleware.

Maybe you have a piece of middleware like

```
app.all("*", function(req, res, next) {
  // not logged in
  if (!req.user) {
    res.render("loginError");
  } 
  // bad accidental next call!! Will call next after rendering login error
  next();
});
```

Comment: Should I be calling something instead of `next()`? Like `return`?

Comment: @BenHumphreyo either `return res.render(...)` or an `else { next() }` would fix this